# .htaccess remove extension from URL with ending / folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using the current code to remove `.shtml` from my URLs for a project of mine:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.shtml
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.shtml
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

It is working perfectly till I make more than one subfolder, such as `/folder1/folder2/`, then it can not find the folder 2 argument. I am not even sure where to go from here to make it work (I don't have much experience at using `.htaccess`)

Answer (score 0):

why not just replace these two lines:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.shtml
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.shtml
```

with

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.shtml -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1.shtml [L]
```